# Converting JavaScript object destructuring to Typescript in arrow function

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions, destructuring

I have converted the following arrow function destructure to Typescript, however I don't understand how to interpret the last item: icon: Icon. This item is not imported or declared.

Original JavaScript:

```
const NavbarDropdown = ({
  children,
  count,
  showBadge,
  header,
  footer,
  icon: Icon
}) => (
  <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar className="mr-2">
    <DropdownToggle nav className="nav-icon dropdown-toggle">
      <div className="position-relative">
        <Icon className="align-middle" size={18} />
```

Converted to TypeScript except an error with {icon: Icon} where Icon is neither imported nor declared anywhere except within the body of the function:

```
const NavbarDropdown = (
    {children} : {children: string},
    {count} : {count: number},
    {showBadge} : {showBadge: boolean},
    {header} : { header: string},
    {footer} : { footer: string},
    {icon: Icon},
  ) => (
    <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar className="mr-2">
      <DropdownToggle nav className="nav-icon dropdown-toggle">
        <div className="position-relative">
          <Icon className="align-middle" size={18} />
```

Update: I understand what this group is referring to regarding Icon/icon and I still cannot find anywhere Icon gets imported or declared.  As suggested here is the code snippet of the NavbarDropdown call:

```
  <Collapse navbar>
    <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
      <NavbarDropdown
        header="New Messages"
        footer="Show all messages"
        icon={MessageCircle}
        count={messages.length}
        showBadge
      >
        {messages.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <NavbarDropdownItem
              key={key}
              icon={
                <img
                  className="avatar img-fluid rounded-circle"
                  src={item.avatar}
                  alt={item.name}
                />
              }
              title={item.name}
              description={item.description}
              time={item.time}
              spacing
            />
          );
        })}
      </NavbarDropdown>
```

Comment: Your TypeScript version has a *completely* different signature to the JavaScript version. Try using `const NavbarDropdown: React.FC<MyPropsInterface> = ...`

Comment: `{children, count,...}: {children:string, count:number,...`  What you have done instead is create a function multiple parameters, instead of a function with 1 parameter that you destruct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues that seem to stand out:

1. Your issue with `Icon`.
2. That isn't how you define the type of a single destructured parameter

Re #1, you've said:

> Converted to TypeScript except an error with `{icon: Icon}` where `Icon` is neither imported nor declared anywhere except within the body of the function

In the JavaScript version, `icon`/`Icon` looks like this:

```javascript
const NavbarDropdown = ({
  children,
  count,
  showBadge,
  header,
  footer,
  icon: Icon
}) => (
```

That `icon: Icon` *looks* a lot like a TypeScript type, but it isn't. It's part of the destructuring. It takes the value of the `icon` property on the object and assigns it to an `Icon` identifier. It's just as though you had this:

```javascript
const NavbarDropdown = (props) => {
    let children = props.children;
    // ...
    let Icon = props.icon;
```

That so the identifier used for it within the function starts with an uppercase character so it can be used as a React component in JSX: `<Icon className="align-middle" size={18} />` (If you had `<icon .../>` instead, it would be an HTML element, not a React component.)

Re #2: Your code id destructuring a series of parameters, one for each property. Instead, you put the type after the destructuring `{}`s:

```
const NavbarDropdown = ({
  children,
  count,
  showBadge,
  header,
  footer,
  icon: Icon
}: {
  children: string;
  count: number;
  showBadge: boolean;
  header: string;
  footer: string;
  icon: React.Component;
}) => (
  <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar className="mr-2">
    <DropdownToggle nav className="nav-icon dropdown-toggle">
      <div className="position-relative">
        <Icon className="align-middle" size={18} />
        ...
```

Or declare a type you can reuse (it may also help with clarity), and then use that type name:

```
interface NavbarDropdownProps {
  children: string;
  count: number;
  showBadge: boolean;
  header: string;
  footer: string;
  icon: React.Component;
}
const NavbarDropdown = ({
  children,
  count,
  showBadge,
  header,
  footer,
  icon: Icon
}: NavbarDropdownProps) => (
  <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar className="mr-2">
    <DropdownToggle nav className="nav-icon dropdown-toggle">
      <div className="position-relative">
        <Icon className="align-middle" size={18} />
        ...
```

But specifically when typing a React functional component, React provides a useful type: `React.FunctionComponent` or its shorter alias `React.FC` (most people use the latter):

```
interface NavbarDropdownProps {
  children: string;
  count: number;
  showBadge: boolean;
  header: string;
  footer: string;
  icon: React.Component;
}

const NavbarDropdown: React.FC<NavbarDropdownProps> = ({
  children,
  count,
  showBadge,
  header,
  footer,
  icon: Icon
}) => (
  <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar className="mr-2">
    <DropdownToggle nav className="nav-icon dropdown-toggle">
      <div className="position-relative">
        <Icon className="align-middle" size={18} />
        ...
```

Note that since you're telling TypeScript the type of the props by using a generic parameter with `React.FC`, you don't have to supply the type in the parameter list anymore.

But normally, `children` in a functional component should be of type `ReactNode`, not `string`. `string` will work because `ReactNode` is a union type and `string` is one of its parts, but it will narrow the type of the children where normally you want to allow the full range of children.

Comment: The only issue with `React.FC`, here though is that the OP has decided `children` is a string instead of ReactNode.

Comment: `Icon` would not be of type `Icon`, but something like `React.Component`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My point was that they likely don't have an `Icon` type at all, the `Icon` type in their code just came from incorrect understanding of destructuring.

Comment: @Keith - Good point about `children`, thanks. Although they *could* require it just be a string, since `ReactNode` is a union and one of the things in the union is `string`, they're allowed to narrow it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Ah, yes.  Didn't think of that.  I tend not to use it, mainly because I often have children doing more than ReactNode allows.  eg. using children as a Promise or callback for async rendering etc..

Comment: @Keith - It was a really good point to raise. :-)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, et al. - thank you for clarifying how to destructure a series of parameters.  I saw a few examples in other threads but clearly misinterpreted.

Comment: @Bergi is correct - Icon is a ReactNode type.  I'm still a bit confused from the original JavaScript, icon: Icon, and why you would do this.

Comment: @im4done That's just a destructuring alias. It's necessary so that you can write `<Icon />` instead of `<icon />` (which either React/TSX or at least the linter complains about, I forgot which)

Comment: @Bergi - I **finally** get what you were saying about `icon`. Sorry, we moved house on Monday and I've been both distracted and exhausted.

Comment: @im4done - I've updated the answer to explain that part, and swapped the order of the issues the answer addresses. Happy coding!